# Facebook APP How to specify permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading the documentation which at a point says "This dialog will request all permissions specified in the User & Friend Permissions section of your app's settings."

However I cannot find the **User & Friend Permissions section** to specify my required permissions.

I'm using the Javascript SDK.

Where/how is it done?

thanks

Comment: I'm using the Javascript SDK.

Comment: heres a link to the permissions reference http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to add is the `scope` parameter, either within your JS SDK (help page mentioned above) or add into your URL call, eg: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream&response_type=token`

You may want to start with [Facebook's Authentication page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) first to understand the oauth flow.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the permissions in the FB.login function (the second parameter after the callback function); 
see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/